# rawquery select as a database input

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to know how to get the value of the selected rawquery

```
Cursor data = dbObject.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM COMAPNY WHERE _id LIKE ?",
                 new String[] { "%" + val2 + "%" });
```

as a sqlite database input. i want to select the number (`val2`) and then put that number to `handle.KEY_ID2` column. is it possible and how to do it?

**FULL CODE**

**DataBase**

```
package test.com;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class handle extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

     public static final String DB_NAME = "SHARE_DB";
     public static final String DB_COMPANYTABLE = "COMAPNY";
     public static final String DB_SHARETABLE = "SHARE";
     public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
     public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
     public static final String KEY_ID2 = "_id2";
     public static final String ROW_ID = "_id";
     public static final String COMPANY_NAME = "Name";
     public static final String COMPANY_SHAREP = "Price";
     public static final String COMPANY_SHAREV = "Volume";

    public handle(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_COMPANYTABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_SHARETABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE = "create table " + DB_COMPANYTABLE + " (" 
                +KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                + COMPANY_NAME + " text not null);";

private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE2 = "create table " + DB_SHARETABLE + " (" 
                + ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                + KEY_ID2 + " integer, " 
                + COMPANY_SHAREP + " text not null, " 
                + COMPANY_SHAREV + " text not null);";
}
```

**Activity1**

```
private ListView.OnItemClickListener listContentOnItemClickListener
   = new ListView.OnItemClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {
Company comid = new Company();
      Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
      int item_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(handle.KEY_ID));

               String item = String.valueOf(item_id);

           comid.setCompanyID(item);    

           startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.next"));
     }};
```

**Activity2**

```
    Company obj1 = new Company();
    String val1 = obj1.getCompanyID();

protected void saveRecord() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    conValue.put(handle.COMPANY_SHAREP, two.getText().toString());
    conValue.put(handle.COMPANY_SHAREV, three.getText().toString());
    conValue.put(handle.KEY_ID2, four.getText().toString());
    dbObject.insert(handle.DB_SHARETABLE, null, conValue);
}
```

As for now i have to enter the KEY_ID2, but what i want is.. when the user click on the ACTIVITY1 list... it send the row id as "val1" & i want that value to be entered on ACTIVITY2 button click

Comment: "COMAPNY"? Are you sure that it is spelled correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing it. You would need to:

1. Make the query to your Database to get the cursor,
2. Move the Cursor to the first element,
3. Get the String/Int/Whatever from the cursor,
4. Insert this value by using an insert.

But I see a very more basic problem here: Your database-layout. It should *never* rely on redundantly saved data!

Please have a look at your Database and check if you can use a relation to make the connection between the two values.

Comment: yes i have added the full code for ur information, i know what you have said above but im having difficulty of implementing the code for it. if u may please help me on that i would be much greateful

Comment: Don't post your whole code. Post the parts you're having problems with.